# How to implement tap targets to fill space with flexbox justify-content space-between?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native, flexbox

Here is the layout that I want:

- Circles of 36px are distributed evenly across width
- Circles are inset horizontally by 16px on both edges of the screen

It works perfectly below, except that the tap targets are only the small gold circles.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.child')).map((x, i) => x.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`Hey child ${i}`)))
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0 }

body {
 background-color: blue;
}

.parent {
  display: flex; 
  background-color: crimson; 
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center; 
  padding-left: 16px; 
  padding-right: 16px; 
}

.child {
  background-color: gold; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  width: 36px; 
  height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I need the tap targets to take up all available space. Tapping anywhere on this crimson box should fire the nearest gold circle.

I achieved this by introducing a mask layer and a bunch of calculations and hacks. Surely there is a better way of keeping the above layout but just having the tap targets expand to fill the available space of the parent? My solution comes with a new set of problems such as accessibility, hover and active styles.

Hack solution below:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.child-mask')).map((x, i) => x.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`Hey child ${i}`)))
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0 }

body {
 background-color: blue;
}

.parent {
  display: flex; 
  background-color: crimson; 
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 16px; 
  padding-right: 16px; 
}

.child {
  background-color: gold; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  width: 36px; 
  height: 36px;
}

.parent-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; 
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: row; 
}

.child-mask {
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 1;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.child-mask:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* 16 + 36 / 2 */
  padding-left: 34px;
}

.child-mask:nth-last-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* 16 + 36 / 2 */
  padding-right: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent-mask">
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
  <div class="child-mask"></div>
</div>
```

Note, the parent could have an arbitrary width, the horizontal padding should always remain 16px regardless of the parent width.

Bonus points if you can get this working using only the subset of css primitives provided by react native as this is my actual use case. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: Would a JS solution be suitable for you?

Comment: Potentially! Can't imagine it would be necessary though, would love to see it!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, the `child` elements will fill all the space so they will be the tap targets, the `::before` pseudo-element will be the yellow circles:

```js
const childs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.child')];
childs.map((x, i) => x.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`Hey child ${i}`)));
document.querySelector('.parent').style.setProperty('--childs', childs.length);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box, padding: 0, margin: 0 }

body {
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: flex; 
  background-color: crimson; 
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  --diameter: 36px;
  --slices: calc(var(--childs) * 2);
  --margin: calc(var(--diameter) / 2 + 16px);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  --width: calc(100% + 2 * calc(100% / var(--slices) - var(--margin)));
  --cut: calc(-1 * var(--width) / var(--slices) + var(--margin));
}
.child:first-child {
  margin-left: var(--cut);
}
.child:last-child {
  margin-right: var(--cut);
}
.child::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: var(--diameter);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.ml, .mr {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
}
.ml {
  left: 16px;
}
.mr {
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="ml"></div>
<div class="mr"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work because there is some dead space where the circles don't overlap ` Tapping anywhere on this crimson box should fire the nearest gold circle.`

Comment: Modified with the latest requirements ;)

Comment: This is actually wrong it doesn't meet the very important requirement `Circles are inset horizontally by 16px on both edges of the screen`

Comment: Thanks for the attempt though, I wouldn't have thought to use `:before`!

Comment: I see, modified. You may not like the approach, I just did it as a know how solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that also doesn't work. I am neutral to the approach, it just has to work. The issue with the latest approach is that the horizontal padding is not actually 16px. It happens to look almost correct because of the width of the stackoverflow snippet but a negative margin of 16px is not equivalent to horizontal padding of 16 https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1690659/167859377-4d38965c-a55e-4117-a2bc-ee09e07fe96d.png

Comment: Do you understand why you solution is incorrect @syduki ?

Comment: @david_adler I don't, do you?

Comment: Please take a look at this codepen and try resizing the window. I have pasted your code inside this codepen. https://codepen.io/mfbx9da4/pen/dydXgrq The left side of the leftmost gold circle should line up with the white line and stay at 16px inset regardless of resizing the window. To repeat the horizontal padding should remain at exactly 16px and should not change.

Comment: Do you see the issue now @syduki ?

Comment: Yes, I even fixed it, not pixel perfect but close, unfortunately JavaScript was unavoidable. Btw, you may check it right here, there is a `Full page` action.

Comment: Maybe you already figured it for yourself, anyway, it was a good CSS challenge! I just could not leave it halfway.

Comment: Very cool really nice job will review in more detail. The truth is I'm actually doing this in react-native, so while it's great to see a solution. This won't solve my real world problem unless it's done with the subset of css in react native.